# How change size of Map in Leaflet v3 React (Inmutable properties)

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, size

I´ve been reading the changelog in v3 and I see several changes.

The Map component is replaced by MapContainer, behaving differently, among other things that props are immutable
I would like to create a MapContainer and be able to update the width and height dynamically, for example when I user minimize the window or when a component changes of size.

How can I do this without kill MapContainer and creating other new ??

```
 <MapContainer whenCreated={...} style={{width:xxx, height:yyy}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use map's "invalidateSize" function:

```
const { height } = useSize(container);
useEffect(() => {
  if (map != null) {
    map.invalidateSize();
  }
}, [map, height]);
```

You can put this in a child of the map as explained in the other anser, or in the parent with map as a ref on MapContainer, it works either way.

MapContainer only needs static style:

```
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
```

No issue anymore (finally)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers above, you can use a custom hook to get the size of your container

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

export default function useSize(ref) {
  const [size, setSize] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current == null) return
    const observer = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => setSize(entry.contentRect))
    observer.observe(ref.current)
    return () => observer.disconnect()
  }, [])

  return size
}
```

Create another component to fetch new tiles every time the map is resized

```
import { useMap } from "react-leaflet";

const ResizeMap = ({ containerRef }) => {
  const map = useMap();
  const { width, height } = useSize(containerRef);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (map) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        map.invalidateSize();
      }, 100);
    }
  }, [height, width]);

  return null;
};
```

Then in your map you can assign a ref to your container and pass that ref to your ResizeMap component

```
const containerRef = useRef(null)

<div ref={containerRef} className="container">
  <MapContainer
    {...props}
    style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
  > 
  <ResizeMap containerRef = {containerRef} />
   ...
  </MapContainer >
<div>
```

This way you can handle the size of your map with any styles defined in the .container class

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same problem after I migrated to **react-leaflet v3.x**

So, I made a trick by using **react-leaflet** `useMap` hook and had a successful attempt to the resize the map based on its container (Whatever it is as well as the window).

So my Map Container code looks like this:

```
  function SetHeightOnChange({ height }) {
    const map = useMap();

    const mapContainer = map.getContainer();
    mapContainer.style.cssText = `height: ${height}px; width: 100%; position: relative;`;

    return null;
  }

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={center}
      zoom={13}
      style={{
        height: height + "px",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <TileLayer
        attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
      />
      <CircleMarker center={position}>
        <Popup>
          A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
        </Popup>
      </CircleMarker>
      <SetHeightOnChange height={height} />
    </MapContainer>
  );
```

**Notice that:** for the map `width`, all you need is to set it to `100%`.

Please also notice the child component inside `MapContainer` which I named it `SetHeightOnChange`. (Make sure to place that child component after `Marker` tag).

Now whenever you trigger an update on height value after any resizing changes, your map size will change accordingly.

Comment: Could you please include how you manage the `height` variable?